# R Shiny html canvas not initialized untill page rescale

Tags: javascript, html, css, shiny, html5-canvas

I am trying to integrate an HTML page with a canvas into my shiny R application using includeHTML(). I use shiny ,shinydashboard, shinycssloaders, dplyr and DT as packages.

It works great only the canvas doesn't get initialized and is a white square with html properties

canvas width="0" height="0" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;"></canvas

When I open Chrome inspect or rescale my browser window it suddenly appears and has the properties

canvas width="592" height="353" style="width: 591.5px; height: 353.297px;"></canvas

Is there a way to fix this problem by e.g. refreshing the canvas or perhaps mimick the rescaling?

I already tried to remove all CSS and compare html before and after scaling but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to trigger the `resize` event with some JavaScript. Maybe like this:

```
js <- "
$(document).ready(function(){
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
});
"
```

and in your Shiny UI:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js))),
  ......
)
```

---

## EDIT

According to your comment, this doesn't work. Maybe:

```
js <- "
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));}, 0);
});
"
```

or

```
js <- "
$(document).on('shiny:connected', function(){
  setTimeout(function(){window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));}, 0);
});
"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it is still not initialized untill I rescale manually. Is there perhaps another way to mimick a rescaling or refresh the canvas?

Comment: @simonmarien See my edit. Could you try? Otherwise you should provide more info about the contents of your HTML file.

Comment: Stephane Laurent. Thank you so much for the help, the first one worked with a timeout of 500.